# Where should I put SOLR Autosuggest configurations

Tags: sxa, content-search, solr

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, there are two cores for the master index now , `instance_name_sxa_master_index` and `instance_name_master_index`, which index should I put the SXA autosuggester configurations at Show Predictions mode.

Comment: I think you have to set it for instance_name_master_index/instance_name_web_index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it should be configured on all indexed where you want to use predictions. If you are still developing your website or styling it you are probably using the master database in editor preview mode. If you would like to have the preductions show there update core for `sxa_master_index`.

If your website is ready (no more development or need to have predictions working in the editor or preview mode) configure it only on the core used for `sxa_web_index` (or any other core which you are using on your CD server).